# index.html not behaving as required in IOS app development

Tags: html, objective-c, css, ios, xcode

My index.html contains following code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
      <title>Index Page</title> 
    </head>
    <body id="bd" style="border:2px solid yellow;width:100%;height:100%">

        <div id="toolHome" class="toolbar" style="postion:fixed;height:40%;top:0;border:2px solid green;width:100%">
            <div id="div1"  style="width:28%;float:left" onclick="edit()">Edit</div>
        </div>

    </body>
</html>
```

The `div id="toolHome"` is kept inside the body, but the body doesn't occupy the entire space. I have tried giving 100% height, 100% width to the body tag also. I have no idea why this is happening. No other file is included in the head section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/aINdqWSz)***

Hi now give to `html and body height:100%;`

as like this

```
html, body{
height:100%;
}
```

***[Demo Live](http://tinkerbin.com/aINdqWSz)***

Comment: Thanks for your immediate reply @rohit